# Php Date formating error

Tags: php, datetime

From a datepicker I'm getting the user input date (`01-01-2018 in d-m-Y format`)
and want to convert it to Y-m-d format so here is what I'm doing:

```
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $desde);

$desde = $from->format("Y-m-d");
```

When I echo `$desde` I get 0018-01-01. Why is this 0018 and not 2018???

Comment: My guess is that the input is `d-m-y` and not `d-m-Y`

Comment: Thank you, you were absolutlely right!!!, should have check that before, than you very much!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can format the output that the `datepicker` delivers ( [see here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) )

So assuming a form input with id `date` then you could format that like this:

```
$( document ).ready( 
    function() { $('#date').datepicker( { minDate: '0', dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' } ); 
});
```